# Install a different version from what's on my Live USB

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I have a 12.04 32-bit Live USB. I want to install 12.04 **64-bit** on my desktop and I'd rather not burn a USB image all over again just to install Ubuntu once (most of my machines require 32-bit for reasons I won't get into; it's only my desktop that wants 64-bit).

Is it possible to just use my existing Live USB to install a different version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not. If there's a i386 system on your stick, you can **only** install an i386 version of Ubuntu. To use the x86_64 version, you need to create the live system again from a x86_64.

What is your problem with creating a new bootstick. It doesn't take long.

PS: Use [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the bootstick. It's the best-working tool I know of.

Comment: The answer to your question is that creating a new bootstick is easy, and _not_ creating one is even easier. Besides, maybe I don't have an extra one lying around. I'm certainly not going to overwrite the one that I've made lots of modifications to. Anyway, I _do_ have another one, so I'll just have to bite the bullet. Thanks.